# How to have multiple children in multiple branches?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, flow-charts, charts

I'm trying to get this organization chart. But my attempts failed to reproduce it. If someone knows how to put multiple children in multiple lines/levels, connected to one node, please show me. It is not necessary to reproduce everything, just the skeleton scheme for something similar...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic way to get the layout in `forest` (and not an attempt to carefully reproduce your screen shot).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={
 grow=south,
 draw,
 double,
 minimum width=3em,
 fill=cyan!10,
},
delay={where content={}{draw=none,fill=none,
    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)}}{}, 
},
 [A,
  [,phantom]
  [B1]
  [B2]
  [,
   [C1]
   [C2]
   [C3]
   [,]
   [C4]
   [C5]
   [C6]
  ]
  [B3]
  [B4]
  [B5]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]